# Save to Google Wallet issue

Tags: android, android-pay

I need to implement save Offer to Google Wallet.
Read tutorial from here https://developers.google.com/wallet/objects/savetowalletnative

But example that attached in tutorial not working.
`com.google.android.gms.wallet.CreateWalletObjectsRequest` is missing in google-play-services_lib and in any other libs from here https://developers.google.com/wallet/objects/libraries

Please help me to run sample application or advice alternative path to resolve my task.

Comment: Did u find an answer for this problem? Im having the same issue

Comment: Was anyone successful importing CreateWalletObjectsRequest?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Cannot compile the code of the example. The doc was last updated March 18, 2015. and I tried with play service 7.3 without success. did you manage to make it working ?